# Iterate through List in JSP using JSF

Tags: java, jsp, jsf

I'm new to JSF and I'm trying to iterate through a `List` within a JSP so I'm using `h:dataTable` but for some reason nothing is printing out but maybe I'm just forgetting something?

```
            <h:dataTable value="#{personBean.person.address}" var="addr">
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                       <h:outputText value="#{postcode}"/>
                    </f:facet>
                </h:column>
            </h:dataTable>
```

These are my imports:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<html>
...
```

This currently DOES work/print out a value:

```
<h:outputText value="#{personBean.person.name}" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumptions:    `List<Address> addresses` is a property of the Person object. And Person is a property of your PersonBean.

Then you can iterate through the address list using data table as shown below:

```
 <h:dataTable value="#{personBean.person.addresses}" var="addr">
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                   <h:outputText value="Postcode"/>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{addr.postcode}"/>
            </h:column>
        </h:dataTable>
```

Comment: In my `personBean` I have a `Person` class that has a bunch of variables of its own like `Name`, `Surname` and `List<Address> addresses`. `Address` is a separate class which has variables like `Street`, `Postcode`, etc. I don't have an `addressList` variable?

Comment: See my modified solution. If it works for you, you can mark my answer as right.

Comment: I tried it but it's just printing "Postcode" as a string, not the actual value

Comment: PersonBean and Person are both just classes with variables with getters and setters. PersonBean does not directly communicate with Person though, it uses: `@EJB
    private PersonService personService;` via `person = personService.getPerson(1);` However, `<h:outputText value="#{personBean.person.name}" />` does print out the value correctly in the same JSP. I have a feeling it's something to do with the version or JSP imports

Comment: If <h:outputText value="#{personBean.person.name}" /> works then <h:dataTable value="#{personBean.person.addresses}" var="addr"> should also work. Make sure the list of addresses in your Person object is not empty.